# Can't delete project libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, refactoring

I want to delete Tomahawk libraries from one of my Eclipse projects, but I get this error:
[image]

Is this some kind of library pollution? Why cant I delete it? I did remove all xmlns calls I had on my pages and also removed calls to all classes from that .jar file.

Comment: Does some other process have a lock on that file? Like, a running JVM?

Comment: Maybe i dont know. How can i check that? How can i stop it and erase the file? My app server and database are stoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg13723.html

or else remove that jar navigating through explorer

Comment: U deleted it from eclipse after a refresh as explained in that link. Thanks.